# sticky banner in footer in mobile not working well in chrome browser in android

Tags: android, css

I have a sticky banner in footer in mobile view in blogger blog that is working well in all browser except google crhome for android. the banner in chrome is getting too much down and haft of it is hiding in footer.

I have this css code:

```
#adBottom { left:-25px !important; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; position: fixed; text-align:center; bottom: 0px !important; width:100%; z-index:999;}}
```

How can I fix it in chrome this?

Tx for anyone that can help..

Comment: Before we get straight to an answer let me know why you are using the backface-visibility property and a negative value for the Left property?

Comment: Hi and tx for your answer. I tried it. I thought it would help. I guess i was wrong?

Comment: HI ed1nh0, Do you have maybe en answer or solution?

Comment: Can Someone please help?? Please....

Comment: I would suggest you try the simple way to do this with #adBottom { bottom: 0; left: 0; position: fixed; right: 0; text-align: center; z-index: 999; }

Comment: Hi ed1nj0 and tx for answering, But that was the original code I used. Because it didn't work in chrome in android, I tried to add the property backface-visibilty (which didn't help). And the left property, was for something else.  So what can I do to dix it in chrome?

Comment: Do you or other know how to fix this? the simple code u suggested doesn't work in chrome in android ...